# I wanted to retrieve data . But I don't know how to do it with this data structure

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Data structure]

This is my code for retrieve data. Is this possible if I use the Calendar to retrieve the current month and current year data?

```
fun getTransaction(){
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    val currentMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val currentYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val uid = auth.currentUser!!.uid
    val key = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Bill").child(uid).push().key!!
    val ref= database.getReference("Bill").child(uid).child(key)

    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            var history = StringBuilder()
            for (item in snapshot.children){
                var category = item.child("category").getValue()
                var expense = item.child("expense").getValue()
                var date = item.child("date").getValue()
                history.append("Category: $category \n Expense: $expense \n Date: $date \n\n")
            }
            tvHistory.setText(history)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work:

```
val key = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Bill").child(uid).push().key!!
```

But if you already know the year and month, you can use:

- `child("2021")` to get a reference to the current year.
- `orderByChild("month").equalTo("6")` to get the nodes matching the month.

So something like:

```
val ref= database.getReference("Bill").child(uid).child("2021")
val query = ref.orderByChild("month").equalTo("6")
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
  ...
```

The rest of your code can remain the same as far as I can see.

Comment: So I can't use like ".child(currentYear.toString()).orderByChild('month').equalTo(currentMonth.toString())"

Answer (score 0):

**1. Add firebase dependency**

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.0')
```

**2. declare a database reference as a global variable**

```
private DatabaseReference db;
```

**3. Data retrival.**

```
db= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("bapECvhg2tebnJr1BTGL9E7mioh1")
                .child("MfS_53SPFJyvMb748kM").child("2021");
        Workout.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               String month=snapshot.child("month").getValue().toString();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
```